# AngularJS Node app downloads instead of loading in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, internet-explorer, angular-ui-router

Whenever I try loading my AngularJS webpage (on a node js + express server) through `http://localhost:3000`, Internet Explorer just tries to **download** it with a random name and no file extension, instead of showing the actual page.

I can't even check the console for errors, because the download attempt seems to start before even trying to load it as a webpage.

The website works perfectly on both Firefox and Chrome. I am using Internet Explorer *11*, so it's not even an old version.

I tried running my index through the [W3 Validator](https://validator.w3.org/), and the only errors it points out in the DOM are the Angular directives and tags (which are not really errors).

I tried changing the DOCTYPE from just a simple `<!DOCTYPE html>` to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-loose.dtd">
```

And this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

... and this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

To no effect.

As suggested in other questions, I also tried serving my page as "text/plain" rather than "text/html" in my node server, but that didn't help either.

Here's the html for my index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="it">
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type"/>
        <!-- Angular Material CSS now available via Google CDN; version 1.0.7 used here -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./modules/angular-material/angular-material.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="icons/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
        <base href="/"/>
        <title>Area Clienti</title>
        <script src="./modules/angular/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="./modules/ngstorage/ngStorage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="./modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="./modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="./modules/angular-material/angular-material.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="./modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="./modules/ui-router-extras/release/modular/ct-ui-router-extras.core.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="./modules/ui-router-extras/release/modular/ct-ui-router-extras.dsr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="./modules/ui-router-extras/release/modular/ct-ui-router-extras.sticky.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="./modules/pdfmake/build/pdfmake.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="./modules/pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="./modules/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ngmaterial.assets.s3.amazonaws.com/svg-assets-cache.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="./js/client.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="App" ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-view ui-view ng-cloak layout="row">
    </body>
</html>
```

The script tags were in the body before, I tried putting them in the head to see if that would have helped, but it didn't.

What might be the issue here? And why is it so painful to make stuff work on IE?

EDIT: here's the server code.

```
var express = require("express");
var fs = require('fs');
var xml2js = require("./node_modules/xml2js");
var auth = require("./authenticator.js");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app=express();

//app.use(express.static('pages'));

var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
   var host = server.address().address;
   var port = server.address().port;
});

var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();       // to support JSON-encoded bodies

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true
}); 
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    sendFile(res, './index.html', getHeader('text/plain'));
});

app.use('/font/', express.static('./font/'));
app.use('/modules/', express.static('./node_modules/'));
app.use('/css/', express.static('./css/'));
app.use('/views/', express.static('./views/'));
app.use('/img/', express.static('./img/'));
app.use('/js/', express.static('./js/'));

function sendFile(res, path, header){
    fs.readFile(path, function(err, content){
        if(err) {
            console.log("\nErrore caricando " + path + " - err: " + err);
            //pageNotFound(res, "error");
        }
        else sendToClient(content, res, 200, header);
    });
}

function getHeader(type){
    return {"Content-Type": type};
}

function sendToClient(data, res, code, type){
    res.writeHead(code, getHeader(type));
    (type === "text/html" || type === "text") ? res.end(data, "utf-8") : res.end(data);
}
```

Plus a bunch of other POST and GET services which I think are not relevant

---

**UPDATE:** I managed to get it to say something in the developer console. This is the error:

[image: error when loading]

(translation: impossible to open http://localhost:3000/)
It still tries to download the page.

---

**UPDATE 2**:

I managed to find out what the issue was: for some reason, the Content-Type header content was being interpreted as an object rather than the string it actually was, so IE couldn't render the page.

It now renders the index, but Angular-UI-Router doesn't seem to work.

It appears as though ui-router can't load sub states (it can switch between normal states though, since I was able to log in and be transferred to my dashboard page, which is a different state)

(Everything is still working perfectly fine on Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: Show the Node/Express code you're using for loading the index.html

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Sorry, I forgot to put the server-side code in. Edited the question

Comment: Can you try putting the `index.html` send after the `express.static` statements? Also can you try using the default Express `sendFile()` without any of the `res.writeHead()` and content type setting and see if that works? Just `app.use('*', function (req, res) { res.sendFile('path/to'file'); });` and after the static resources path is set.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky The problem was with my function getHeader. I simply kept my sendFile method but, instead of using getHeader, I manually wrote {'Content-Type':type}. See updated question

Comment: Ok, that's great to hear. You may want to post that as a separate question to identify issue with router configuration.

Comment: Yes, was thinking that would be the best approach :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

Could it be sending you a file because you're using .sendFile():

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    sendFile(res, './index.html', getHeader('text/plain'));
});
```

instead of using .render() to render the page?

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index.html');
})
```

Comment: Note that sendFile is a custom function I created, I'll add it to the question for clarity

Comment: Sorry, right I'm using ejs to render ==> app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

you'd need to npm install ejs as well....

Answer (score 0):

Try using Express's `use()` to always send via [sendFile()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) the `index.html` after **any** HTTP action using the `*` wildcard. Make sure this goes **after** any other API REST routes or similar. This helps ensure that the Angular app within index.html is not constantly reloaded by other pages being rendered. This way any other API routes send/receive the data you need and only if nothing else is matched, will the `index.html` be loaded. Below is a structure that worked for me for an Express + Angular 2 application.

File Structure:

```
api
    foo
        foo.js
    bar
        bar.js
public
    fonts
    css
    img
    index.html
server.js
```

Server JS:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// fonts, css, images are stored in respective folders within folder "public"
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// some RESTful endpoints
app.use('/api/foo', fooRoutes);
app.use('/api/bar', barRoutes);

app.use('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html')));

// error handling middleware
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```